# setup or exe files not found

Tags: software-installation

Downloaded Adobe Flah player, went to downloads to run setup, opened the downloaded file but there was no (exe, setup or install). And when I searched on this issue, I had to read a long procedure of copying things here and there. It is just a hassel to install an outsider software. 
Is there a rule on this matter?

Comment: Ubuntu is not a Microsoft Operating System and does not use .exe files. It is using apt as package manager and in general you get >95% of all software directly via apt. Flash is somehow a special case - and as mentioned in your other post - it might make sense to just install Google Chrome as it comes with a bundled Flash version.

Comment: "Outsider" software is generally expected to package a .deb file which you can install with one click. Unfortunately, Flash refuses to spend 5 minutes packaging its software properly. Anyways, Adobe discontinued Flash as a download for Linux. It is now provided as a plugin by Firefox and built-in by Chrome.

Answer (score 0):

the only way to get flashplayer working on linux now is to install chrome or chromium which has a built in plugin. Adobe don't directly support linux anymore for flash (or much else)